# python question Class return object and store list

Tags: python

I new to python and I have the code below:

```
class Order:
    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_type

    def __init__(self, order_type, price, quantity, direction):
        self.order_type = order_type        
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.direction = direction

class OrderBook:
    def __init__(self, bids=[], asks=[]):
        self.bids = SortedList(bids, key = lambda order: -order.price)
        self.asks = SortedList(asks, key = lambda order: order.price)

    def submit(self, order):        
        if order.direction == 'buy':
            self.bids.add(order)
            self.bids= sorted(self.bids,key = lambda order:order.price)
            print(self.bids)
        elif order.direction == 'sell':
            self.asks.add(order)
            self.asks= sorted(self.asks,key = lambda order:order.price)
            print(self.asks)
    def remove(self, order):
        if order.direction == 'buy':
            self.bids.remove(order)
        elif order.direction == 'sell':
            self.asks.remove(order)

res1 = OrderBook()
print(res1.submit(Order("AAPL",70,1,'buy')))

print(res1.submit(Order("DIS",70,1,'buy')))
print(res1.submit(Order("DIS",80,1,'buy')))
```

it returns below:

```
[<__main__.Order object at 0x106d7e908>]
None
```

I want to use the submit function to store multiple orders to bids/asks, and sort by price.
e.g.input: Order("AAPL",70,1,'sell'),Order("DIS",15,2,'buy'),Order("DIS",15,1,'buy')

What Syntax should I add to my code, and how to print my bids/asks list?

Comment: You should explain how the existing code doesn't do what you want.

Comment: You don't need to use `sorted()`, since `SortedList` automatically sorts.

Comment: Thanks! I removed sorted() , and print(self.bids). It returns SortedKeyList([<__main__.Order object at 0x106cfa1d0>], key=<function OrderBook.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x106d99950>). how could I display the data?

Answer (score 1):

**To the list insert problem:**

If you wanna to send a list of objects to submit, you can do something like this:

```py
def submit(self, order):
    #if input are a single order 
    if isinstance(order ,Order):        
        if order.direction == 'buy':
            self.bids.add(order)
            self.bids= sorted(self.bids,key = lambda order:order.price)
            print(self.bids)
        elif order.direction == 'sell':
            self.asks.add(order)
            self.asks= sorted(self.asks,key = lambda order:order.price)
            print(self.asks)
    #if the input ar a list of orders
    elif isinstance(order ,list):
        #for each object in list
        for o  in oreder:
            if o.direction == 'buy':
                self.bids.add(o)
                self.bids= sorted(self.bids,key = lambda x:x.price)
            elif order.direction == 'sell':
                self.asks.add(order)
                self.asks= sorted(self.asks,key = lambda order:order.price)
                print(self.asks)

    else: 
       #do something if input is not expected, or pass
       pass
```

and finaly use this:

```
res1.submit([Order("DIS",70,1,'buy'), Order("DIS",80,1,'buy')])
```

or:

```
orderList =[Order("DIS",70,1,'buy'), Order("DIS",80,1,'buy')]
res1.submit(orderList)
```

**To the print problem:**

You need to declare a method to parse your object to string with a patter you  want for both objects, like this:

```
class Order:
    # ...
    def __str__(self):  
        pattern_to_print = "instance of Order('{}',{},'{}')".fomat(order_type, price, quantity, direction)
        return pattern_to_print
```

this will print something like this :

```
>>> print(Order("DIS",70,1,'buy'))
instance of Order('DIS',70,1,'buy')
```

**Note:** in your code you are trying to print the result of `OrderBook.submit`, that hasn't any return, so it's `None`